# Recorrer carpetas y subcarpetas python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero realizar una pequeña función para mover a una carpeta todos los archivos que sean ".mp3".

Para ello he pensado recorrer todas las carpetas y subcarpetas en una dirección dada, y lo que se me ha ocurrido es lo siguiente:

```
def catch(dir_name):

for item in os.listdir(dir_name):
    print(str(item))
    if item.endswith(".mp3"):
        shutil.move(str(dir_name + "/" + item), "E:/Users/path/destino")
    if os.path.isdir(item):
        print("subcarpeta" + os.path.join('E:','\Users','path',item))
        catch(os.path.join'E:','\Users','path',item))
print("Termino la revision")
```

Usando esto, solo me realiza la primera pasada por las carpetas, pero no me realiza de forma recursiva la búsqueda en las subcarpetas.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint

def sdir(path):
    c=0
    elements={}
    if not os.path.isdir(path) or not os.access(path, os.R_OK):
        raise Exception('pls check path or permits')
    try:
        dirs= os.listdir(path)
    except Exception as e:
        p=path.split("/")
        elements[p[len(p)-2]]="denied access"
        return elements

    for value in dirs:
        if os.path.isdir(path+value):
            pdir=value.replace(path,"").strip("")
            sub=sdir(str(path+value+"/"))
            elements[str(pdir)]=sub
        else:
            elements[c]=str(value)
        c=c+1
    return elements

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(sdir("audio/"))
```